# MYSQL SELECT statement inside CONCAT function

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I was trying to do something like this in my very big select statement, this code snippet is from the SELECT part of the query

```
CONCAT((SELECT alias.`date` FROM alias WHERE id IN(latest_id)),'<-',GROUP_CONCAT(
`alias`.`date` ORDER BY `alias`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '<-')) AS "date_chain"
```

but I am getting NULL in "date_chain" column. If I only write this

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
`alias`.`date` 
ORDER BY `alias`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '<-') AS "date_chain"
```

It works.

But I want to concat the latest date in the start of this chain.

adding full SQL

```
SELECT latest_id,CONCAT((SELECT alias.`date`FROM alias WHERE id IN (latest_id)),'<-',
GROUP_CONCAT(
  `alias`.`date` 
  ORDER BY `alias`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '<-'
)) AS "date_chain" FROM alias WHERE latest_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY latest_id;
```

Kindly can someone help me what is missing in my first syntax? Thank you

Comment: If you need further help you need to provide full query. Also, best way of debugging queries like that is to run simple `SELECT` statements separately to see "where the `NULL` happens" :)

Comment: I have added to full sql to main question.

Comment: Please put this in your question - let's respect the reader. It's unreadable this way.

Comment: yes.. I am sorry. I was doing that.. sorry again!

Comment: Your query should be rewritten - it's not efficient. But anyways, run `SELECT date FROM alias WHERE id = latest_id` and post number of rows that you get from this query.

Comment: it still returns NULL.. =(

Comment: How many rows did this query return (it can't be null - it's 0 or more)? If more than 0, what are the values returned in column `date`?

Comment: So i get a lot of rows but this particular column "date_chain" is null for all the rows. I get around 55k rows.

Comment: There is no reason to be sad. All of your values in column `date` that the query produces are `NULL` which is why my answer applies. Read it to see that if any argument is `NULL`, `CONCAT()` would also return `NULL`.

Comment: i think the select query inside concat does not get the value of latest_id. Otherwise I dont see a reason why it will produce a NULL date.

Comment: Why would you think that? We've already established that every `date` is `NULL` for every row in table `alias` that matches a condition `id = latest_id`

Comment: I can see a result for this SQL if replace "latest_id" with an actual latest_id value

`SELECT DATE FROM alias WHERE id = '431030';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75332/discussion-between-consider-me-and-mi-sarwar).

Comment: Edited my answer with more efficient query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When any value that's an arugment for `CONCAT()` function is `NULL` - the output of function evaluates to `NULL`. See  [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for reference.

> CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Try `CONCAT_WS()` where you can also specify a separator.

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.

However, don't put `NULL` as separator - that would cause the result to yield `NULL`.

**Edit after comments**

We established that the reason for this was improper use of outer query column `latest_id` as a feed for inner `SELECT`.

```
  SELECT alias.`date`FROM alias WHERE id IN (latest_id)
```

was just comparing each `id` to `latest_id` from the same row, while the desired result was to compare it to column from outer `SELECT` block.

Query after changes should be

```
SELECT 
  latest_id,
  CONCAT(
    (SELECT alias.`date`FROM alias WHERE id IN (o.latest_id)),
    '<-',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      `alias`.`date` ORDER BY `alias`.`date` DESC SEPARATOR '<-'
    )
  ) 
  AS "date_chain" 
FROM alias o
WHERE latest_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY latest_id;
```

Though your query gives you what you want it is not the best way to achieve this result. You should in most cases avoid using `CONCAT()` because of `NULL` values and your `SELECT` inside an outer `SELECT` block as a column feed would make the query run slow (it must compute values for every row).

Please consider the following code as better practice to get the same result

```
SELECT
  foo.latest_id,
  CONCAT_WS('<-', a.date, foo.group_concat) AS date_chain
FROM(
  SELECT  
    latest_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(date ORDER BY date DESC SEPARATOR '<-') AS group_concat
  FROM alias
  WHERE latest_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY latest_id
) foo
LEFT JOIN alias a ON
  foo.latest_id = a.id
```